# Is there a commonly accepted way of noting that a person makes a non-word sound in a transcription?

Tags: sounds

I'm transcribing the lyrics of a song into written text. Towards the end of it there's a short recording of someone telling a little anecdote about their day. As this audio reaches its end, he chuckles. Is there a commonly accepted way of noting that a non-word sound was made in the audio when transcribing it?

Comment: Sometimes movie subtitles use square brackets, such as [dog barks] and [chuckles].

Comment: What do you mean "transcribing the audio"? Do you mean writing the notes to the song? Or writing down the words to the song??

Comment: @Lambie Words, thanks for the question. I'll update the post.

Comment: In the scripts for The Simpsons, Homer's "D'oh" is written as "(annoyed grunt)"

Comment: I would use parenthesis, like they do in theater and scripts. (chuckles)